# Azure Container Instances - how to mount volume from Azure File Share through the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances, azure-files

is it possible to somehow mount volume from Azure File Share during the creation process of ACI instance within the Azure Portal directly in "Container Instances"? Or mount volume must be embedded within the image or referenced to container solely through the "az" commands?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no place to set the mount volume if you create the ACI in the portal through the ACI resource directly. The only way, as I know, to create the ACI in the Azure portal is using the Azure template. Take a look at the steps that [Create ACI via Template in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-template). And in the template, use the [volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/containergroups#Volume) to set the mount volume.

Comment: thank you.
Same can be achieved with manual az CLI commands I suppose? Thank you

Comment: @AndreyDonald Of course, you can. Take a look at the CLI command [`az container create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_create) with the parameter `azure-file-mount-volume-xxxx`.

Comment: thank you. Could you please assist me with this questions as well? Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65909620/azure-container-instances-from-where-to-execute-docker-login-before-we-execu

Comment: @AndreyDonald Of course, I will take a look.