# Azure Container Instances - from where to execute "docker login" before we execute "az container create" command

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

we need to deploy ACI - Azure Container Instance in private virtual network.
We followed the example and prepared YAML file from this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet
So now we need to execute before that our command:

```
az container create --resource-group myResourceGroup --file vnet-deploy-aci.yaml
```

in that yaml we are referencing our image, similarly like from the above example (just we are using our private repo )

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld
```

I do not have permission to execute this because of Azure permissions, so I sent this yaml file to one of Azure admins but he does not have experience with containers, so he is , as well as I am confused from where he should trigger and execute `docker login repo` command and enter credentials, before he execute the `az container create`.

Can you please provide me some guidance since I did not see that on that Azure docs link as well but I suppose that "docker login" command is required before we trigger "az create" command which deploys our yaml?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to execute the command `docker login` when you use the YAML to create ACI. You just need to use the `imageRegistryCredentials` option to configure the credential for the private registry.

And if you use the image `mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld`, then you do not need any credential, as I know, it's a public image. So you only need to follow the steps in the doc you provide.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It's a private repo.
Can I instead of putting those within the YAML file to set credentials during the execution of "az container create" command like this:
`--registry-login-server <acrLoginServer> --registry-username <service-principal-ID> --registry-password <service-principal-password>`

so my full command can be:
`az container create --resource-group myResourceGroup --registry-login-server=xxx.dev --registry-username=test --registry-password=test --file ads=test.yaml`

Comment: @AndreyDonald It seems you can't do that. The three parameters just support the single image when you use the parameter `--image`.

Comment: I do have single image within my yaml file.
So what do you think from this perspective?
Sorry for asking you a lot but I do not have permissions to do it myself and test but I need to send to the Admin.
Thank you and I marked response as answer

Comment: @AndreyDonald If you only have one image to deploy, maybe you don't need to use the YAML file, just need to use the command `az container create` with the three parameters and the `--image` parameter.

Comment: I do have to use YAML since there are many other parameters which I need propagate - mount volume, networking, ports etc.
What do you think should it work with those 3 parameters in `az container create` or should I prepare a new YAML and add those in YAML? THANK YOU

Comment: @AndreyDonald Of course, these three options, you can also find in the CLI command. Still the advice, single image with CLI command and multiple images with YAML file. But you can also choose YAML file for a single image, it's also OK.

Comment: can you please take some time to assist me on this very strange issue which I am facing? Thank you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65997987/azure-container-can-not-login-to-private-registry-error-response-received-fro