# Azure Container - can not login to private registry "Error response received from the docker registry"

Tags: azure, docker, docker-registry, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

from Azure we try to create container using the Azure Container Instances with prepared YAML.
From the machine where we execute `az container create` command we can login successfully to our private registry (e.g private.dev on JFrog Artifactory ) after entering password

```
docker login private.dev -u svc-faselect
Login succeeded
```

We have YAML file for deploy, and trying to create container using the `az` command from the SAME server.

```
az container create --resource-group FRONT-SELECT-NA2 --registry-login-server="private.dev" 
--registry-username=svc-faselect --registry-password="..." --file ads-azure.yaml

An error response is received from the docker registry 'private.dev'. Please retry later.
```

I have only one image in my YAML file.
I am having real big problem to debug why this error is returned since Error response does not provide any useful information.
Search among the similar network issues but without success:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-troubleshoot-access

Comment: Do you use DockerHub or ACR(Azure Container Registry) as docker container registry?

Comment: Hi. No, as mentioned we use our private repo.
My company is using ARTIFACTORY JFrog for private repository and as presented we can do the docker login without an issue from the same machine.
But if trying to login during the "az container create" command with properties dedicated for connecting to private repo and for pulling the image, this command files.

I am not sure what to do... maybe somehow if we can see more error details...

Comment: Did you try to use following example?
https://jfrog.com/blog/kubernetes-registry-for-azure-container-instances/

Comment: @AndriyBilous thank you for your response, I wouldn't like to introduce Jenkins complexity for this BUT as you can see they are doing the integration in the exact same way (except I defined NAME and IMAGE within the yaml file) but registry login server, password and username are being used

`az container create --name mycontainer --image
jfrogtraining-docker-dev.jfrog.io/node-version:latest --registry-login-server
jfrogtraining-docker-dev.jfrog.io --registry-password $ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD --registry-username
jainishs --resource-group myResourceGroup --ip-address public --port 
3000`

Comment: maybe I did wrong because I put equal sign "=" in between the registry property values for server, username and password???

Comment: I think yes. Here is the manual
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_create-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few moments that could be the reason of your problem.

There should be no **=** at az container create options
**--registry-login-server --registry-password and --registry-username**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_create-examples

Command should look like

```
az container create --resource-group FRONT-SELECT-NA2 --registry-login-server jfrogtraining-docker-dev.jfrog.io --registry-username svc-faselect --registry-password "..." --file ads-azure.yaml
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66008830/azure-containers-deployment-operation-failed-with-status-200-resource-state did you maybe face the similar issue? Thanks